# Help with a holiday cryptic crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

I'm trying to finish off a cryptic crossword these holidays. I'm down to the last three clues and I simple cannot figure them out. Can you help with the following clues? I've included the letters I have after the clue.

- Rank little child with a large head (5) __T_L
- Be discriminating about the egoist's treatment (9) G_E___I__
- Leap to action in ball game (6) ___O_A

A brief explanation with your answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rank little child with a large head (5) __T_L

> TOT + AL = TOTAL

Be discriminating about the egoist's treatment (9) G_E___I__

> THEEGOIST* = GHETTOISE

Leap to action in ball game (6) ___O_A

> LEAPTO* = PELOTA